# Surround matching siblings with element in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

How do you surround matching neighbour siblings with a new element in XSLT?

In this example, the elements to surround are those matched by `bar[@baz='quux']`:

XML input:

```xml
<foo>
    <bar>X1</bar>
    <bar baz="quux">X2</bar>
    <bar baz="quux">X3</bar>
    <xnorfzt>X4</xnorfzt>
    <bar baz="quux">X5</bar>
</foo>
```

Expected XML output:

```xml
<foo>
    <bar>X1</bar>
    <new>
        <bar baz="quux">X2</bar>
        <bar baz="quux">X3</bar>
    </new>
    <xnorfzt>X4</xnorfzt>
    <new>
        <bar baz="quux">X5</bar>
    </new>
</foo>
```

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Yep, it does, @michael.hor257k :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
**in XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="@baz='quux'">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <new>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </new>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

See transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvt6XR

**in XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::bar][@baz = 'quux']]" priority="1"/>

<xsl:template match="bar[@baz = 'quux']">
    <new>
        <xsl:call-template name="wrapbar">
            <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </new>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="wrapbar">
    <xsl:param name="node"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$node"/>
    <xsl:if test="$node/following-sibling::*[1][self::bar][@baz = 'quux']">
        <xsl:call-template name="wrapbar">
            <xsl:with-param name="node" select="$node/following-sibling::*[1]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

See transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvt6XR/1